# Is there any difference betwwen writing each and every member of struct to a file and writing structure object directly to a file in c++?

Tags: c++, file

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
struct example
{
 int num1;
 char abc[10];
}obj;

int main () 
{
 ofstream myfile1 , myfile2;
 myfile1.open ("example1.txt");
 myfile2.open ("example2.txt");
 myfile1 << obj.num1<<obj.abc;  //instruction 1
 myfile2.write((char*)&obj, sizeof(obj)); //instruction 2
 myfile1.close();
 myfile2.close();
 return 0;
}
```

In this example will both the example files be identical with data or different? Are instruction 1 and instruction 2 same?

Comment: `In this example will both the example files be identical with data or different?` This is something you can easily test.

Comment: Have you checked the docs?

Comment: Difference - yes.  Both examples the same -  no.  The member by member text ("<<") stream output (of instruction 1) will not reflect padding contained in binary write of instruction 2.  And the binary 'write' of instruction 2 will not store readable text of instruction 1.

Comment: they are not the same. not by a long shot. but i am too lazy to write a good answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a massive difference.

Approach 1) writes the number using [ASCII encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII), so there's an ASCII-encoded byte for each digit in the number.  For example, the number 28 is encoded as one byte containing ASCII '2' (value 50 decimal, 32 hex) and another for '8' (56 / 0x38).  If you look at the file in a program like `less` you'll be able to see the 2 and the 8 in there as human-readable text.  Then `<< obj.abc` writes the characters in `abc` up until (but excluding) the first `NUL` (0-value byte): if there's no `NUL` you run off the end of the buffer and have undefined behaviour: your program may or may not crash, it may print nothing or garbage, all bets are off.  If your file is in text mode, it might translate any newline and/or carriage return characters in `abc1` to some other standard representation of line breaks your operating system uses (e.g. it might automatically place a carriage return after every newline you write, or remove carriage returns that were in `abc1`).

Approach 2) writes the `sizeof(obj)` bytes in memory: that's a constant number of bytes *regardless of their content*.  The number will be stored in binary, so a program like `less` won't show you the human-readable number from `num1`.
 Depending on the way your CPU stores numbers in memory, you might have the bytes in the number stored in different orders in the file (something called [*endianness*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness)).  There'll then always be 10 characters from `abc1` even if there's a `NUL` in there somewhere.  Writing out binary blocks like this is normally substantially faster than converting number to ASCII text and the computer having to worry about if/where there are `NUL`s.  Not that you normally have to care, but not all the bytes written necessarily contribute to the logical value of `obj`: some may be [padding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment).

A more subtle difference is that for approach 1) there are ostensibly multiple object states that could produce the same output.  Consider `{123, "45"}` and `{12345, ""}` -> either way you'd print "12345".  So, you couldn't later open and read from the file and be sure to set `num1` and `abc` to what they used to be.  I say "ostensibly" above because you might happen to have some knowledge we don't, such as that the `abc1` field will always start with a letter.  Another problem is knowing where `abc1` finishes, as its length can vary.  If these issues are relevant to your actual use (e.g. `abc1` could start with a digit), you could for example write `<< obj.num1 << ' ' << obj.abc1 << '\n'` so the space and newline would tell you where the fields end (assuming `abc1` won't contain newlines: if it could, consider another delimiter character or an [escaping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character)/quoting convention).  With the space/newline delimiters, you can read the file back by changing the type of `abc1` to `std::string` to protect against overruns by corrupt or tampered-with files, then using `if (inputStream >> obj.num1 && getline(inputStream, obj.abc1)) ...process obj...`.  [`getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) can cope with embedded spaces and will read until a newline.

Example: `{258, "hello\0\0\0\0\0"}` on a little-endian system where sizeof(int) is 32 and the stucture's padded out to 12 bytes would print (offsets and byte values shown in [hexadecimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal)):

```
              bytes in file at offset...
              00  01  02  03  04  05  06  07  08  09  0a  0b  0c  0d  0e  0f

approach 1)   32  35  38  69  65  6c  6c  6f
              '2' '5' '8' 'h' 'e' 'l' 'l' 'o'

approach 2)   00  00  01  02  69  65  6c  6c  6f  00  00  00  00  00  00  00
              [-32 bit 258-]  'h' 'e' 'l' 'l' 'o''\0''\0''\0''\0''\0' pad pad
```

Notes: for approach 2, `00 00 01 02` encodes `100000010` binary which is 258 decimal.  (Search for "binary encoding" to learn more about this).

Comment: you might add about endianess and padding. Also about the `\n` `\r` debacle

Comment: What a depressing comment ;-).  I made a half-arsed go of it.  Cheers.

Comment: sorry about that mate :). Good answer

Comment: just a note: `sizeof(obj)` can be different (and very likely will) from `sizeof(int)+10`, due to the way compiler lay outs the struct in memory (alignment and maybe something else?) see [this](https://onlinegdb.com/H1Web3unz) as example. But everything else hit the point IMHO.

Comment: @GianPaolo: oh yeah - well spotted.  Cheers